# Should the featured photo be shown on meta?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, featured-photo

On my computer, the featured photo is shown only on the main site, not on meta. Should the featured photo be shown on meta as well?

Answer (score 3):

Meta does not support adding the custom side bar currently.  This would require development by Stack Exchange developers to implement.